# How do I keep magic users from destroying my world? WIP!

Tags: magic

The problem I am having is that my magic is simply too powerful for my world where a noob with a simple book can destroy the entire world, there are also many other problems that I won't speak of now because I am attempting to ask one distinct question. Now the two magic systems have a serious power-level problem, in fact all of them do, but these two are similar enough to be the same question.

So I guess I should state the universal laws of magic first. (Some of which are my hypothesis of more fundamental physics (and also some real ones))

Energy cannot be created or destroyed (2nd law of thermodynamics).

Mass is made if energy (e = mc^2).

Energy is split into two indivisible units, the basic and the infinite. (The first law of energy (hypothesis (but real in my world))).

The infinite indivisible can absorb energy but cannot release any (second law of energy(total fiction)).

All reactions tend to a single infinite indivisible particle (third law of energy (total fiction)).

Magic never breaks any of these rules. Why is this important? Well let me just list.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what sort of recommendations you'd be looking for. Broadly I'd suggest you weaken your world's magic/apply limitations to it, but I'm assuming you've already thought of that and it's not the sort of answer you want.

Comment: I am wanting specific limitations to specific problems...

Comment: Your choices are keep this blackhole suitcase nuke wish machine magic and tell a story that fits that world, or change your magic to allow the story you want to tell.

Comment: "The problem I am having is that my magic is simply to powerful for my world where a noob with a simple book can destroy the entire world," - do not put that book in that world. Simple as that, really. Such books belong to world's mythology, not their reality.

Comment: You asked for a lot: you say you want specific methods for specific problems, and yet you have 4 entire *systems* of problems. The way this site works, you should ask things in a way that one method could possibly answer whole question. Oh, and since each method would effectively be a redesign, we need to know which parts of your design are crucial to the story you want to tell, and which are open to alterations.

Answer (score 1):

Good thing that since you made these magics up, you can make them up a different way.

1. Ithlia - if the problem is that people can know everything by astrally projecting themselves, I can think of 2 solutions.

A:  **Astral plane is dangerous.**  There is scary stuff that lives there.  It is easy to get messed up.

B:  **There are infinite worlds.**. Ithlia does not distinguish between the infinite dimensions.  You can explore a world psychically and it might be your world or it might be a very similar world which for your purposes is the same.  But it might differ enough that the information you obtain is bad and not true for the world where your physical body resides.  Or the world you explore might differ radically which should become obvious as you wander around.  You can waste a lot of time exploring the infinite worlds and come back without much useful information.

2. Kyros.

A. You point out that some random dude can cause limitless trouble.  Have the changes one can make be proportional to magic energy you personally have, or your magic organ size or what have you.  Ordinary folks are capable of making only small scale changes even if they get the book.  You have to be Joe Magic to really mess with things.

Comment: I am taking of the first part because I am editing the question to where it doesn't include that.